# Recurrent h12 timeouts on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sidekiq, puma

We are getting recurrently timeout errors on Heroku. When we look into our logs to find some clues about what can be the reason for that, we could not find a good reason for it. These timeouts are generally occurring not in the busiest times, but something like random times.

We are using `puma` as web server and `sidekiq` as background job processor.

Our configurations for puma is; `MAX_THREADS=60`, `WEB_CONCURRENCY=1`.

Our configuration for sidekiq is; `WORKER_CONCURRENCY=8`.

We are using `single Standard-2x` dynos for worker and web.

We are using `standard-0` posgresql package with `120` connection limit. We have `DB_POOL=60` configuration for matching the same number with the thread count. With these configurations, we are not using all connections.

#### puma.rb

```rb
thread_count = ENV.fetch("MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads thread_count, thread_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RACK_ENV") { "development" }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 1 }
preload_app!

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

plugin :tmp_restart
```

[image: Heroku Metrics]

As you can see from our metrics, it is occurring on some random times, not in the busiest times that we get more requests.

What can be some potential reasons for us to get these timeouts? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: My first instinct is to checkout out background processes as Heroku blames them for most timeout issues. I know you should have the resources to handle a lot, but can you describe some of your more resource intensive tasks? Sending out e-blasts? Processing large chunks of data?

Comment: We don't have generally resource intensive tasks. But we have one background job that generates an SQL query that takes ~2-3 seconds to complete. When the 8 same job run concurrently, can it be a reason for us to get these timeouts? These jobs are running recurrently, all the day.

Comment: Are you sure this is server related? Also, consider that thread based concurrency might solve blocking IO in the response, but it won't help with CPU intensive routes (since the Ruby GIL will allow the busy thread to disrupt the process). Perhaps using more processes (workers) would help?  -  P.S. I'm iodine's author, and would recommend that you test your application with iodine to see if this is server related (which I doubt). I think you'll discover it's one of the routes performing a CPU heavy task.

Comment: @Myst Is it possible to one thread blows up a process, and then all the remaining requests that are currently handled by other threads to also fail and wait for a new available process and threads?

Comment: @eyupatis - when a thread kills a process, any open connections are closed by the OS in a semi-graceful way. This **should** signal the client (Heroku) and/or the master process that something went wrong. You'd get different error messages in the log, including Puma error messages. [Puma re-spawns failed workers](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/ca03c520757e4ed1caab28bf4f60ec2ffe5b2585/lib/puma/cluster.rb#L190-L213) the [same as iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/f4f38701bfa1d127de340cd7b60fc20df025da1e/ext/iodine/fio.c#L3832-L3882) - both log the event.